# How do I run Typescript tests for Jasmine\Karma through a TFS Build Process

Tags: c#, angularjs, typescript, tfs, karma-jasmine

I have a web application using Angular 1.5 with bower/npm/gulp coded in Typescript to do our build. Our back end is a c# .net WebApi2. Both are built and deployed on TFS2015. My c# nUnit tests are easy to integrate as part of the build process. The Typescript jasmine unit tests however are more difficult to integrate. How do I get my Typescript jasmine unit tests to run as part of the TFS build and if they fail, fail the build? We have them running through a Jasmine Spec runner and also Karma but not integrated.

I have read the many posts on StackOverflow integrating Javascript unit tests and each avenue took me through an overly complex solution that didn't work. These include Powershell scripts, Chutzpah amoungst others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than try to recreate the Specrunner via Chutzpah on the build server, which I found difficult to configure and get working. The aim was to get karma to output the running tests in the 'trx' test format that TFS recognises and then publish them to the build. Please note I am using PhantomJs to run my tests through Karma but won't cover that here as it is well covered elsewhere.

1) install the [karma-trx-reporter plugin](https://github.com/hatchteam/karma-trx-reporter) via npm into your web project (or similar plugin)

2) Configure the Karma.config to include the trx reporter

```
reporters: ['dots', 'trx'],

trxReporter: { outputFile: 'test-results.trx' },

// notify karma of the available plugins
plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-trx-reporter',
],
```

3) Create a Gulp (or grunt) task to run the karma tests if you don't already have one. Run the task locally and check it creates the 'test-results.trx' specified above. (It doesn't matter where the file is created on the build server):

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src(['tests/*.js']).pipe(karma({
        configFile: __dirname + '/Testing/karma.config.js',
        singleRun: true
    }));
});
```

4) Add a Gulp (or Grunt) TFS build task to run the karma tests created in the previous step and output the trx file.
[image]

5) Add a Gulp (or Grunt) TFS build task to Publish the test results and merge them into the build. Note that the "Test Result Files" path is a wild card **/*.trx to find any trx files in the build path (i.e. finds our previously created file). "Merge Test results" is checked to Merge both our Jasmine test run and our c# test run into the same session. "Continue on error" is unticked to ensure any jasmine test failures break the build.

[image]

You will notice two sets of tests that have been run and included as part of the build!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the steps. I have the karma tests running on a remote VM. Do you know how to get them back to the controller so the build can find the trx file?

Comment: The two options you have are; altering the outputFile property of the Karma.config or, altering the Tests Results Files property of the Publish Test Results TFS Build task. The alternative is to move your running tests to the same machine as the build agent. That was my preferred option. I have the karma-pantomjs plugins installed in the project so there isn't any additional downloads\config in order to get the tests running.

Comment: Here's my write up on what I had to do: https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/17028/Karma-Test-Results-with-TFS-Build/25020#.V9vpEyErJhE

Comment: @AlignedDev Looks like your website is kaput (didn't find an archive.org backup either). New URL?

Comment: @ruffin Thanks for the heads up. I've moved to www.aligneddev.net and didn't port that article over.
I found part of it from my old site: https://web.archive.org/web/20200807101818/http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2016/09/16/karma-test-results-with-tfs-build.aspx